# Implementation of FitzHugh-Nagumo diffusion model diverging by first iteration

Tags: java, algorithm, processing, convolution, laplacian

I'm trying to implement the model described in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340641416_Parallel_simulation_of_pattern_formation_in_a_reaction-diffusion_system_of_FitzHugh-Nagumo_using_GPU_CUDA) paper, which *simulates the equation proposed by Alan Turing of the FitzHugh-Nagumo model in 2D as a model for forming animal skin patterns* — in other words: simulating two substances diffusing across a surface, how they interact with each other, and what patterns arise. This is the paper's result:

[image]

I've implemented it (*my interpretation of at least*) in Processing/Java, but it's not working like it should (values are diverging lots, *even* by the first iteration), so I'm wondering what's going wrong in my implementation (included at the end of the post).

---

These are the 3 relevant parts from the paper regarding implementation:

#### 1. U & V

There are two substances, u and v (which can be thought of as an activator and inhibitor respectively)
[image]

#### 2. Finite difference equations

A fairly simple pixel convolution is defined for each value (pixel) of *u* and *v*. Values for a given pixel on the next generation are calculated using both it and its neighbours' current-iteration values.

The value of *u* on the n+1 iteration for a given pixel (i,j) is defined as:
[image]

The value of *v* on the n+1 iteration for a given pixel (i,j) is defined as:
[image]

#### 3. Constants they used

[image]

---

So the problem I'm getting is that the values of *u* and *v* are quickly diverging to infinity/NaN (I expect they should stay within 0...1 although the paper doesn't explicitly mention this). *v* seems to diverge first, taking *u* along with it, as can be seen here (for some constant index):

```
0.94296926 0.77225316 // u, v after random initialisation
0.91600573 -62633.082 // values after first iteration -- v has already diverged massively
63.525314 5.19890688E8 // second iteration -- even more divergence
-520088.38 -2.98866172E14 // ...and so on...
1.40978577E14 1.2764294E19
-Infinity -1.7436987E24
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
```

### Code

```
//Parallel Simulation of Pattern formation in a reactiondiffusion system of Fitzhugh-Nagumo Using GPU CUDA
// Alfredo Gormantara and Pranowo1

static final float a = 2.8e-4; 
static final float b = 5.0e-3;
static final float k = -0.005;
static final float tau = 0.1;
static final float delta_t = 1e-3;

float[][] u; // activator
float[][] v; // inhibitor

void setup() {

  size(512, 512);

  frameRate(5);

  u = new float[height][width];
  v = new float[height][width];

  for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < u[0].length; j++) {
      u[i][j] = random(1); // random of max of 1 ?
      v[i][j] = random(1); // random of max 1?
    }
  }

  loadPixels();
}

void draw() {

  float[][] u_n_1 = new float[height][width]; // array holding the n+1 iteration values of u
  float[][] v_n_1 = new float[height][width]; // array holding the n+1 iteration values of v

  float denom = 2f / width; // 2/MESH_SIZE -- I think mesh_size is dimension of the grid 
  denom*=denom; // square for denominator
  
  println(u[34][45], v[34][45]); // print vals of one location to see divergence

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

    int negative_y_i = y-1 < 0 ? height-1 : y-1; // wrap around grid
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

      final float u_n = u[y][x];
      final float v_n = v[y][x];

      int negative_x_i = x-1 < 0 ? width-1 : x-1; // wrap around grid

      // calculate laplace (12)
      float u_n_1_laplace = u[y][(x+1) % (width)] + u[y][negative_x_i] + u[(y+1) % (height)][x] + u[negative_y_i][x]; //n+1th iteration

      u_n_1_laplace -= (4 * u_n);
      u_n_1_laplace /= denom; // divide by (2/DIM)^2
      u_n_1_laplace *= a;

      // calculate n+1th iteration u value
      u_n_1[y][x] = u_n + delta_t*( u_n_1_laplace + u_n -(u_n*u_n*u_n) - v_n + k );

      // calculate laplace (14)
      float v_n_1_laplace = v[y][(x+1)% (width)] + v[y][negative_x_i] + v[(y+1)% (height)][x] + v[negative_y_i][x]; //n+1th iteration
      v_n_1_laplace -= (4 * u_n);
      v_n_1_laplace /= denom; // denom is really small, so value goes huge
      v_n_1_laplace *=b;

      v_n_1[y][x] =  v_n + (tau/delta_t)*( v_n_1_laplace + u_n - v_n);

      pixels[y*width + x] = color((int) ((u_n_1[y][x]-v_n_1[y][x])*255));
    }
  }

  u = u_n_1.clone(); // copy over new iteration values
  v = v_n_1.clone(); // copy over new iteration values
  updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: This is a god question, but is liable to get closed due to the 3 questions you've asked, even though they are related. Perhaps you could rephrase it as "what am I doing wrong?" and add more details about how your values are diverging.

Comment: @cigien My question regards a **single problem**: the fact that my implementation isn't working. 

I'm merely offering 3 possible causes (in question form) of it why could be wrong to give others something to start with. This post *is* focused as there's only 1 problem and 1 correct objective answer.